# Provisioning issues for Adobe Air iOS apps when using an outside developer

Tags: ios, air, provisioning, certificate

My outside developer insists that it is best practice for me to obtain the certificate and to provision for testing from my computer. That seems different than what Apple recommends. One of her reasons is that with Adobe Air she otherwise does not need Xcode. Is she right?

To complicate matters, I do not have a Mac. I can borrow one at will so I have access to a Mac. However, I'd strongly prefer not to install Xcode on it. My developer believes that there is a way to use the keychain without Xcode. Is that possible and how would I do it?

If the app is successful, I'll break down and get a Mac. At that point, will it be easy to transfer the keychain to the new Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Search in Spotlight for "Keychain Access."  That is your keychain.  Yes, you can transfer things from system to system via exporting p12 files.  What exactly are you asking?  You haven't really given any details about your situation.  You need a provisioning profile with a valid certificate that has the device in question added to it in order to add anything onto a device in general (although I've heard that Adobe skirts this somehow...).

Comment: Thanks @borrrden. I'm a PC guy, so most Mac and iOS concepts are new to me. The first two questions are important. Is it best practice for me to provision the app for testing instead of the developer? Is there a way to provision without using Xcode?

Comment: As far as I know the only way to insert a provisioning profile onto a device is through XCode, or its command line tools (which you have to install XCode to get anyway...).  Normally the person releasing the app will be the one to provision it.